# Javascript to change html table dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm trying to create an overview of a repository, similar to how GitHub displays the project overview, except I want mine to be on a single page that changes dynamically.

So I want to create the table with a base overview, and then clicking different rows shows the rows contents (if the element in that row has contents).

Here is what I have right now, but I'm having trouble getting the rows to have an link element that actually updates the table. If I call the function from the console, it looks like it works fine, it's just the link to that I really need help with I think.

JS:

```
var Table = document.createElement('table');

function updateTable(node) {
    Table.innerHTML = "";
    if (node.children !== undefined){
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++){
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            if (node.children[i].hasChildren){
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.setAttribute('onclick', "updateTable(" + node.children[i] + ")");
                a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.children[i].name));
                tr.appendChild(a);
            } else {
                tr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.children[i].name));
            }
            Table.appendChild(tr);
            document.getElementById('table').appendChild(Table);
        }
    }
}

var node = {name:'a', parent: null, children:[], size:0, hasChildren:true};
var node11 = {name:'gsidfhuo', parent: node1, children:[], size:0, hasChildren:false};
var node12 = {name:'sdlj', parent: node1, children:[], size:0, hasChildren:false};
var node1 = {name:'aasdf', parent: node, children:[node11,node12], size:2, hasChildren:true};
node.children.push(node1);
var node2 = {name:'ahtrs', parent: node, children:[], size:0, hasChildren:false};
node.children.push(node2);
var node31 = {name:'gsidfhuo', parent: node1, children:[], size:0, hasChildren:false};
var node3 = {name:'aawsefd', parent: node, children:[node31], size:1, hasChildren:true};
node.children.push(node3);
var node4 = {name:'aikuyr', parent: node, children:[], size:0, hasChildren:false};
node.children.push(node4);



updateTable(node);
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="txt"> Test Table</h1>
    <font style="font-size:+3"><table id="table" border="1px" style="width:50%"></table></font>
  </div>
  <script src='App.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

`a.setAttribute('onclick', "updateTable(" + node.children[i] + ")");`

You are concatenating a String with an Object (node.children[i]), and so the result of the expression is the string `updateTable([object Object])`, which is why the call fails.

Since the [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) attribute on an element accepts a string, it may not be what you're looking for. Instead, you can attach a click event listener like this:

```
a.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent){
  // onclick behavior here
}
```

Comment: Alright, I've tried that and now the table doesn't work at all. The initial table that's constructed from node displays node31, node 3, and node 4. And it doesn't update at all if I click on those links. Looking at the elements in the browser, the event listener doesn't appear in the line with the link either. I removed the a.setAttribute that you mentioned, and replaced it with a.addEventListener('click', updateTable(node.children[i]));